How should I manage Git for a multi-phase project to facilitate future improvements and bug fixes?
I've just completed the first phase of a multi-phase assignment for a course, and it is working fine. However, I didn't use any version control tools like Git during its development. Now that I am starting the second phase, I want to initialize a Git repository to manage my code more effectively.
Here are my concerns:

Should I initialize the Git repository now and track the entire
project from this point onward, including the first phase that is
already complete?
Is it advisable to use the same repository for both phases of the
assignment, or should I create separate repositories for each phase?
I am worried that if we separate the repos, any future improvements
or bug fixes in phase one will need to be applied to both
repositories, which doesn't seem efficient.
Would using branches for different phases be a better approach?

Any guidance on how to proceed with version control for this project would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Your question is hard to answer in a sensible manner, since you gave us zero information on how the source code, documents, software of the different phases are related to each other (we could discuss different scenarios, but it would be easier you give a better explanation). Please edit your question accordingly. Note also the format of this site is not well suited for asking 4 questions in one post. Questions ignoring this recommendation will get closed by our community regularly. Start by deleting question #4  from the post, it will undoubtly trigger close votes ("opion based").

Are you working alone on that assignment, or as a team?

Voting to delete, it seems you  have lost interest in this topic.


I want to initialize a Git repository to manage my code more effectively

For teams, a version control system (VCS) is essential. For a solo developer, you're honestly not going to see a huge amount of value from using a VCS, git or otherwise. Absolutely there are some things it enables, mostly "aaargh, everything I've done for the past two days is wrong, can I have the old version back please?", but you can manage those in other ways.
That's not to say it's not a valuable skill to learn, because when/if you step into the world of professional development, you will be working in a team and you will almost certainly be using git.

Is it advisable to use the same repository for both phases of the assignment, or should I create separate repositories for each phase?

Absolutely one repository. One of the points of a VCS is that there is a single source of truth for your code; I can't think of a good reason for a solo developer to have the same codebase in two repos.

Would using branches for different phases be a better approach?

Branches are really there for when you have multiple simultaneous workstreams; that can happen with a solo developer but again is something which much more naturally happens with teams. If "end of phase 1" is a point in time, you can just tag the repo at that point and continue working on your main branch from there.

I noticed you haven't mentioned Pull Requests.
Using PRs (Pull Requests) and setting Releases would give you what you are looking for in a single repo.
Lock down main with settings so that no changes can directly occur to it.
Do the all the work in branches, use PRs to accept work into main.
Release versions for previews, aphas, betas, etc.
Is this the type of thing that you are looking to accomplish?
This is a very straightforward use of git. Github for example includes a "Issues" system to create branches and automatic much of the described processes.
You can do it via git command line without GitHub or GitLab.
UPDATE: I wrote this answer with an eye on the future of informal or formal second dev. My logic doesn't really match OP's question as asked.
UPDATE #2: As the comments pointed out, my thinking was 180 degrees off for a lone wolf dev on a single PC/Laptop. Which is what the OP asked for. My answer is more suitable for a team or (possibly) even single person that uses multiple PCs/Laptops that may ask a friend for a code review.

PRs make not much sense for a solo dev.

@DocBrown  I assumed two things from the question. The need/desire to clearly document as work in merged into main.  Second, the possibly or likelyhood of getting a someone to join the project.

The document of work merged into main is the commit history. PRs are a github artifact not a fundamental part of git.

You only need to have PRs if you have multiple copies of a repository

@Caleth - As I get pummelled (rightly so), I forget that the rest of the world doesn't typically use multiple PCs/Laptops and have other people sometimes do code reviews. Lone wolf on a single PC/Laptop isn't my world. I upvoted your comment.
